# Client accessing /usr/local/apache/htdocs/ on CPanel

Tags: php, apache, security

I looked through my logs this morning and I was surprised to see:

```
[error] [client 92.222.69.48] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/php-my-admin
[error] [client 92.222.69.48] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-3.5.8-rc1
[error] [client 92.222.69.48] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-4.0.0-rc1
[error] [client 92.222.69.48] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-3.5.7-1
[error] [client 92.222.69.48] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-3.5.7
[error] [client 92.222.69.48] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-3.5.6
[error] [client 92.222.69.48] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-3.5.5
[error] [client 219.232.247.108] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/iviv
[error] [client 219.232.247.108] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin
[error] [client 219.232.247.108] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/pma
[error] [client 219.232.247.108] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/myadmin
```

There are about 300 lines that are similar.

I'm running WHM and Cpanel with multiple websites.

My question is how is someone accessing **/usr/local/apache/htdocs/** ?

All other requests show up as  **/home/****/public_html/**

```
[error] [client ME] File does not exist: /home/****/public_html/phpmyadmin
[error] [client ME] File does not exist: /home/****/public_html/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Someone is probing your server in an attempt to gain access to it. These things happen and you should ban that IP address if you have that option.

Comment: Already did. I understand what they are doing - Just want to know how they can access that directory?

Comment: Ah, http://yourserverip/php-my-admin example.

Comment: Thats what I thought. But It forwards to my main domain and registers as /home/maindomain.com/public_html/phpmyadmin in the logs :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well in case anyone ever runs into this again, Ill answer my own question.

I am using WHM, with 64 IP addresses. Most of those are assigned to an account within WHM.

When you try to access dedicatedip/phpmyadmin it forwards to the domain.

However, If you have an unassigned IP address that is not linked to an active account you get the result above.

DOH! Thanks to @LuckyBurger for his comment.